# How do I rename the columns of a Pandas DataFrame using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe that has column names like below, with some of the column name having substring within []

```
'date', 'customer','region[level1]','priority[s2]','planning[WIP]' ...
 Jan.10,  ABC     ,   East[3]      ,    Normal[1] ,    TBD[WIP]    ...
```

I want to rename all the columns so that only the value within the [] is kept.

```
'date','customer','level1','s2','WIP' ...
```

I've tried below code but kept getting error code 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'. Which part went wrong?

```
import re
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
  df.columns.value[i] = [re.match(r"[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]", col_name).groups()[0] for col_name in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- `re.match` only searches for a match at the start of string, use `re.search` to look for matches anywhere inside a string
- `[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]` matches zero or more chars other than `[` and then `[`, zero or more chars other than `]` and then `]` and [it looks good](https://regex101.com/r/aN2hp2/3), but it is a pattern that you should use with `.str.replace` (see below).
- You get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` issue because some headers do not match your pattern (see the regex demo above.)

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan.10','ABC','East[3]','Normal[1]','TBD[WIP]']], columns=['date','customer','region[level1]','priority[s2]','planning[WIP]'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'.*\[([^][]*)].*', r'\1', regex=True)

>>> df
     date customer   level1         s2       WIP
0  Jan.10      ABC  East[3]  Normal[1]  TBD[WIP]
```

The `.*\[([^][]*)].*` regex matches

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `].*` - `]` char and the rest of the line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN2hp2/2).

Answer (score 2):

You can try `str.replace`
Details on the regex found [here](https://regex101.com/r/VVGojz/1)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['date','customer','region[level1]','priority[s2]','planning[WIP]'], columns=['col'])

df['col'].str.replace(r'(.*\[)|(\].*)', '', regex=True)

# 0        date
# 1    customer
# 2      level1
# 3          s2
# 4         WIP
# Name: col, dtype: object
```

To change column names

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1]], columns=['date','customer','region[level1]','priority[s2]','planning[WIP]'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(.*\[)|(\].*)', '', regex=True)

#   date    customer    level1  s2  WIP
# 0 1   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `apply` and `re.sub()` like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan.10','ABC','East[3]','Normal[1]','TBD[WIP]']], columns=['date','customer','region[level1]','priority[s2]','planning[WIP]'])

df.rename(columns=(lambda x : re.sub(r'(.*\[)|(\].*)', "", x)))
```

Output:

```
    date    customer    level1    s2            WIP
0   Jan.10  ABC         East[3]   Normal[1]   TBD[WIP]
```