# Using Regex groups to rename columns in a pandas dataframe by matching multiple patterns at a time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename, regex-group

I have the following list of columns of a data frame `df`
`cols_2 = ['state', 'population', 'male population', 'female population', 'working population', 'male  working population', 'female working population' 'female population in the age group 0 to 6 years', 'male population in the age group 0 to 6 years', 'population in the age group 0 to 6 years']`

For natural reasons I would like to compress names as follows:
Any occurrences of  `population` to `pop`, `male`  to `m_`, `female`  to `f_`, `working`  to `w` and `in the age group 0 to 6 years` to `_minor`

Please note the spaces being included in the pattern

This [Stack overflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112631/how-do-i-rename-the-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-using-regex#:%7E:text=To%20change%20column%20names%20df%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%20%28%5B,WIP%20%23%200%201%201%201%201%201) is the starting point, where the requirement is only getting rid off square brackets by matching to a single pattern.

My aim is to obtain multiple matches for multiple patterns

Really appreciate any kind of help!

PS: This is my first time here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import re

new_cols = []

pat = re.compile(r"(?:fe)?male\s*|population|working\s*")
for col in cols_2:
    new_col = pat.sub(
        lambda g: f"{g[0][0]}_" if g[0][0] in "fmw" else f"{g[0][:3]}", col
    )
    new_col = new_col.replace(" in the age group 0 to 6 years", "_minor")
    new_cols.append(new_col)

print(new_cols)

# to replace the columns in DataFrame then:
# df.columns = new_cols
```

Prints:

```
[
    "state",
    "pop",
    "m_pop",
    "f_pop",
    "w_pop",
    "m_w_pop",
    "f_w_pop",
    "f_pop_minor",
    "m_pop_minor",
    "pop_minor",
]
```